# How to sort data in JQgrid in codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting, jqgrid

Below is my controller function. When I click on column to sort data it sends request to model to get the sorted data but I'm modifying the data within the for loop to add some customized data for some columns. So I written the usort function to sort the data coming from the for loop but it is sorting data only on the current page. I'm newbie in JQGrid. Please help out here.

```
  public function getReports() {
        $arrResponceData = new stdClass();
        $strOrderByField = $this->input->get('sidx'); //get oderby field from grid
        $strOrderBySort = $this->input->get('sord'); //get sirting order
        $arrFilters = $this->input->get('filters');
        $intZerothPosition = 0;
        if (isset($arrFilters)) {
            $intSeletctedYear = $arrFilters[$intZerothPosition]['rules'][$intZerothPosition]['data'];
        }
        $arrSet['intSeletctedYear'] = $intSeletctedYear;
        $arrSet['strOrderBySort'] = $strOrderBySort;
        $arrSet['strOrderByField'] = $strOrderByField;
        //  print_r($arrSet);
        $this->session->set_userdata('accmeParsReport', $arrSet);
        if ($strOrderByField == "template" || $strOrderByField == "country" || $strOrderByField == "caseDiscussion") {
            $strOrderByField = "activity_name"; //userId is getting from query paramater
        }
        $arrAllActivityCount = $this->User_model->getAllActivityDetails($intLimit = "", $intStart = "", $strOrderBySort, $strOrderByField, $intSeletctedYear); //get total user count

        $intPage = $this->input->get('page'); //get to page count from grid
        $intLimit = $this->input->get('rows'); //get to show total records at a time in grid
        $intPageCount = 0;
        if (count($arrAllActivityCount) > 0) {
            if ($intLimit != 0) {
                $intPageCount = ceil(count($arrAllActivityCount) / $intLimit);
            } else {
                $intPageCount = count($arrAllActivityCount);
            }
        }
        if ($intPage > $intPageCount)
            $intPage = $intPageCount;
        if ($intPage < 1)
            $intPage = 1;
        $intStart = ($intLimit * $intPage) - $intLimit;
        $arrActivityDetails = $this->User_model
                ->getAllActivityDetails($intLimit, $intStart, $strOrderBySort, $strOrderByField, $intSeletctedYear);
        $arrResponceData->page = $intPage;
        $arrResponceData->total = $intPageCount;
        $arrResponceData->records = count($arrAllActivityCount);
        $strTemplate = 'Template D';
        for ($intIndex = 0; $intIndex < count($arrActivityDetails); $intIndex++) {
            $strStrToTime = strtotime($intSeletctedYear);
            $dateMyFormatForView = $intSeletctedYear;//date("Y", $strStrToTime);
            $intAMAPraCredits = $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['credit_hours'];
            if ($arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['isBundled'] == "yes") {
                $strYear = date('Y', strtotime($arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['expiration']));
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['expiration'] = $strYear . "-12-31 00:00:00";
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['credit_hours'] = $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['intCrditHours'];
                $intAMAPraCredits = isset($arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['activityCompletedUsers']) ? $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['activityCompletedUsers'] : "0.00";
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['certificate_title'] = $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['certificate_title_name'];
            }
            $arrResponceData->rows[$intIndex]['cell'] = array(
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['activity_id'],
                $strTemplate, $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['accme_id'],
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['prov_id'], $dateMyFormatForView,
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['certificate_title'], $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['expiration'],
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['city'], $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['state'],
                'USA', $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['providership'],
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['pars_type'], $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['credit_hours'],
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['do'], $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['notDo'],
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['comm_support'], $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['competence'],
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['comp_eval'], $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['performance'],
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['perf_eval'], $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['outcomes'],
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['out_eval'], 'No',
                'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'No',
                $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['providers'], $intAMAPraCredits,
                '', $arrActivityDetails[$intIndex]['patient_care'],
                );
        }

        if ($strOrderByField == 'certificate_title') {

            if ($strOrderBySort == 'asc') {

                $sort = $arrResponceData->rows;

                usort($sort, array($this, 'method3'));

                $arrResponceData->rows = $sort;
            } else {
                $sort = $arrResponceData->rows;
                usort($sort, array($this, 'method4'));
                $arrResponceData->rows = $sort;
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($arrResponceData);
    }
```

Comment: Most likely the sorting should be accomplish by your query in the model and not after the data is retrieved from the DB. Whether that can be implemented may depend on you sort methods.  Please edit your question and include code for  both your model and usort  methods.

Comment: Yes you are right @DFriend. Somehow I managed to do that in query. Right now my problem is resolved. But still I would like to know is it possible in controller. My sorting functions are working accurately but JQgrid only displays the sorted result for that particular page because server side pagination. Thanks for replying.